# How to display same detailed help in Pycharm as in Jupyter?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

When in Jupyter I Shift+TAB on pandas.DataFrame, it displays e.g.

Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data
structure with labeled axes (rows and columns). Arithmetic operations
align on both row and column labels. Can be thought of as a dict-like
container for Series objects. The primary pandas data structure.

Is there any way to display this in Pycharm as well? Quick documentation (Ctrl+Q) doesnt display this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is `help(pandas.DataFrame)`. Prints the same information as shift+TAB does in Jupyter.